# Resolver método de inserción mediante Visual Basic con Listbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, algoritmos

Buenas noches compañeros, he estado programando un ordenador de números mediante el método de inserción directa, en el cual me he estado guiando con un pseudocódigo de  mi clase de Estructura de Datos, el problema es que al momento de dar clic en el botón de "ordenar" deja de responder el programa XD, sería de mucha ayuda cual podría ser el problema:

```
     If rbburbuja.Checked = True Then
        'Ciclo Para
        For i = 0 To lstnumeros.Items.Count - 1
            'Ciclo Para
            For j = 0 To lstnumeros.Items.Count - 2
                'Ciclo Sí
                If (lstnumeros.Items.Item(j) > lstnumeros.Items.Item(j + 1)) Then
                    Auxiliar = lstnumeros.Items.Item(j)
                    lstnumeros.Items.Item(j) = lstnumeros.Items.Item(j + 1)
                    lstnumeros.Items.Item(j + 1) = Auxiliar
                    lstnumeros.Show()
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El Código del lstnumeros.Show() No Debe de Aparecer hay, También Puedes Activar Los Errores y Ver que error se produce y su descripción pero con este pequeño código al final y comentando esta línea puedes ver que eso no debería de fallar...

```
On Error Resume Next
    If rbburbuja.Checked = True Then
            'Ciclo Para
            For i = 0 To lstnumeros.Items.Count - 1
                'Ciclo Para
                For j = 0 To lstnumeros.Items.Count - 2
                    'Ciclo Sí
                    If (lstnumeros.Items.Item(j) > lstnumeros.Items.Item(j + 1)) Then
                        Auxiliar = lstnumeros.Items.Item(j)
                        lstnumeros.Items.Item(j) = lstnumeros.Items.Item(j + 1)
                        ' Aquí Se Produce un Error en el Último Registro
                        If j <> lstnumeros.Items.Count - 2 Then
                           lstnumeros.Items.Item(j + 1) = Auxiliar
                        Else
                           lstnumeros.Items.Add( Auxiliar)
                        End If
                        'lstnumeros.Show()
                        lstnumeros.Text = Auxiliar
                        If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox(Err.Description)
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        End If
```

Comment: No dejes múltiples respuestas, edita una sola y añade lo que haga fAlta; este no es el modo de usar la plataforma

Comment: ok, es que me equivocado en la primera...

Comment: Pues dale en editar y borra la segunda por que haz hecho esto muchas veces en otras preguntas

Comment: Ya esta resuelto.

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus aportaciones :) Quedo funcionando gracias